# Get container domain from inside the Iframe js

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe

I'm trying to get the domain name of the host website of my Iframe is there a way to do that?
I would really appreciate any help regarding this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can try something like this: `const url = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer : document.location.href;`

Comment: But keep in mind, there is cross domain policy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Yeah actually it worked for the same domain but I'm trying to use it with different domains
I don't know if there is a work around for that. Like something from the back end

Answer (score 0):

so I got the answer after working on it for a while 
we can get the url from the host website by using this method
or by adding the an event to the iframe like this but yeah its working now